# How to properly nest an If/Else statement?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to set multiple cookies. if a specific cookie exists another one is set. 
i.e if cookie "1" exists i set cookie"2" and if cookie 2 exists i set cookie "3" and so on.

i am trying to achieve that with an if/else statement which i couldn't get to work.

```
if(getCookie('1')) {
    setCookie('2',1,365);
} else {
    if(getCookie('2')) {
        setCookie('3',1,365);
    } else {
        if(getCookie('3')) {
            setCookie('4',1,365);
        } else {
            if(getCookie('4')) {
                setCookie('5',1,365);
            } else {
                setCookie('1',1,365);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What i want to achieve is show different messages for a returning visitors to my site. not just for the 1st time visit but until their 10th visit .

Comment: Looks like strange logic, try this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/5e8tx8bu/**

Comment: @adeneo it. doesn't seem to work

Comment: Please elaborate on *I couldn't get to work*. What happens?

Comment: no cookie is set at all - nothing happens

Comment: Works for a single if/else statement

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you use a loop. Interate through the desired values, and if it exists, you add it +1... If none is set, the default one is applied...

```
var cookieToSet = "1";
for(var i=1; i<=4; i++) {
    if(getCookie(i)) {
        cookieToSet = i+1;
        break;
    }
}
setCookie(cookieToSet', 1, 365);
```

Comment: That looks like a neat solution, but my cookies may not always be in a consecutive order.

Comment: Decided to use this method, but it keeps getting stuck after setting 2 cookies ... i am using this. http://jsfiddle.net/vevogyry/

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
if(getCookie('1'))
    {
    setCookie('2',1,365);
    }else if(getCookie('2'))
    {
        setCookie('3',1,365);
     }else if(getCookie('3'))
     {
            setCookie('4',1,365);
     }else if(getCookie('4'))
     {
          setCookie('5',1,365);
      }else
      {
           setCookie('1',1,365);
      }
```

or else use switch case for it , hope it will work for you !!